# Issue with VS 2010 and XBAP

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xbap

In VS 2010, I've created a new WPF Browser Application project. Once the project has been created, I started the project by pressing the F5 key to run or debug it. Now Firefox opens and shows me a dialog to download the XBAP file or to execute the file with another application(IE). Normally IE starts up, if I double click on the XBAP file in windows. Anyway, VS uses the wrong browser. In there an option in VS to set the IE as the default browser instead of Firefox?

By the way, in the project settings => Debug is an option were I can set the start up program. Of course, I can set there IE as the right browser. The problem is that I must set this option in every project and every time when I want to start a XBAP.

Are there fixes or updates for VS? (I'm using Windows 7 BTW)

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem by set the IE as the default browser. Now it works now. The drawback is that Firefox is now not longer the default browser.